# Integral, but for products?

Tags: calculus

If I want to sum a continuum of things near zero, I can do an integral. What if I want to multiply a continuum of things near one?

Specifically, I would like to do something like this:
$$
\lim_{N\rightarrow\infty}\prod^N_{n=0} \left(1+\frac{f(n/N)}{N}\right)
$$
If $f$ is a constant, it becomes a well-known characterization of $e^f$. What happens when $f$ isn't?

Comment: Intuitively, I'd expect this to come out to $\exp(\int_0^1 \ln(1+f(x))\,dx).$ But I haven't thought how to prove it yet.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_integral